# Android layout_gravity for TextView in Java

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I want to change the *layout gravity* for a *TextView*.
Via XML, you'd do that via `android:layout_gravity="value"`.
I know that in order to change the *gravity* itself, via XML you'd do `android:gravity="value"`, and in Java you'd do `textview.setGravity(Gravity.VALUE);`
But sadly, there's no `textview.setLayoutGravity(VALUE);`, so I'm stuck.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use the correct sub class. For example if your `TextView` is in a `FrameLayout`, you would need to:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Be aware that `layout_gravity` or `setLayoutGravity` sets your current elements gravity in its parent, `gravity` or `setGravity` sets gravity for your current elements content within the element. Refer the illustration below for more details.

**Example 1:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</FrameLayout>

---------------------------------------------
|Some Text                                  |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Example 2:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</FrameLayout>

---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|            Some Text                      |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Example 3:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</FrameLayout>

---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                 Some Text                 |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Example 4:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</FrameLayout>

---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                 Some Text                 |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

**Example 5:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Text" />

</FrameLayout>

---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                 Some Text                 |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Your answer  combined with my answer gave me the solution!

Answer (score 2):

To set layout_gravity programmatically

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
youttextview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Note: layout_gravity do not work with relative layout

Comment: The parent layout of the TextView is a relative layout. What should I do?

Comment: See Redman answer for relative layout, if you want to add this programmatically then use addRule method like layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

Comment: My wrong. The parent of the TextView is a relative layout, nested in a frame layout.

Answer (score 0):

In Linear Layout Use :

```
android:layout_gravity="value"
```

In Relative layout use properties :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

as per your requirement

Comment: What about frame layout?

Comment: you can use gravity for frame

Answer (score 0):

The TextView was surrounded by a HorizontalScrollView which was surrounded by a ScrollView.
I discovered that nothing worked, *until* I set in the XML file:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" <!-- The value was "wrap_content" before, hence couldn't work -->
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <!-- Some more code -->
```

Later on, I simply used:

```
textview.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

And it solved my problem.

Thanks a lot to everybody!